# RSpec let method not generating variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm trying to create a test for my `bill_total` helper method. The let method isn't generating the `bill1` and `bill2` variable.

```
describe BillsHelper do
  let(:bill1) { Bill.create(name: 'Bill 1', amount: 1.00) }
  let(:bill2) { Bill.create(name: 'Bill 2', amount: 1.00) }

  describe "#bill_total" do
    bill1.amount = 1.00
    bill2.amount = 1.00

    expect(bills_helper.bill_total).to eq(2.00)
  end
end
```

Error:

```
    /Users/adrianleeelder/Documents/Developer_Resources/sites/bills_app/spec/helpers/bills_helper_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `bill1' for #<Class:0x007fb3c121b548> (NameError)
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in `subclass'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:228:in `describe'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/Documents/Developer_Resources/sites/bills_app/spec/helpers/bills_helper_spec.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in `subclass'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:228:in `describe'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/Documents/Developer_Resources/sites/bills_app/spec/helpers/bills_helper_spec.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /Users/adrianleeelder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
[Finished in 2.4s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The names defined in `let` statements are only available within `before` and `it` blocks, not within the outer level of the `describe` blocks.  If you replace your inner `describe` with `it`, the names will be accessible. Also, the names are not actually variables, but `helper methods`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write your examples inside `it` blocks, not `describe` blocks:

```
it "#bill_total" do
  bill1.amount = 1.00
  bill2.amount = 1.00

  expect(bills_helper.bill_total).to eq(2.00)
end
```